# How I autocomplete other textfields with bootstrap when I update a field (using typeahead in Ruby on rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have a problem when I use bootstrap.

I want to autocomplete a text field and when it complete, that autocomplete others textfield too.

**Example:**

![Autocomplete][1]

In this example, when I complete the field name, I want to autocomplete the surname and the cargo field.

My code is:

**controller:**

```
def new
    @personales            = Personal.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js ...
      format.json ...
    end
  end
```

**view:**

```
<%= javascript_tag "var personales = #{ personales.to_json };" %>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#name').typeahead({
    source: personales,
    updater: function(item) {
        return item;
    },
    highlighter: function(item){
        return item;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have my answer helped you? If yes, please accept it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar, in the source I grab the json using a jquery get, I store the patients in an array, after that I store an map with the json of each patient using the name as key. In the updater method I update the fields I wanted.

Here is the coffee code:

```
jQuery ->
  map = {};
  $("#request_patient_name").typeahead
    source: (query, process) ->
      return $.get("/worker/patients.json", {query: query}, (data) ->
          patients = data
          names = []
          $.each data, (index, item) ->
            names.push(item["name"])
            map[item.name] = item
          return process(names)
        )
    updater: (item) ->
      $('#request_patient_id').val(map[item].id).trigger('change')
      $('#patient_birthdate').html(map[item].birthdate)
      $('#patient_gender').html(if map[item].gender then "M" else "F")
      $('#patient_mothername').html(map[item].mother_name)
      $('#patient_cpf').html(map[item].cpf)
      return item
```